# Can't trigger events inside an expanded DIV that is housed inside it's "trigger DIV"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a div that I want to expand on click. Using either Bootstrap Collapse or AngularUI Collapse this works fine if I place a div inside the div I want to collapse. The code looks like this:

```html
<div id="closestShip">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#closeShipExpand">Nærmeste skøyte<img width="10%" src="/app/content/images/stedsmark.svg"><img /></a>
  <div class="collapse" id="closeShipExpand">
    <div id="closeShip1">
      <div class="closeShipNM"><span>4,2</span> nm</div>
      <div class="closeShipName">{{Skoyte.Navn}}</div>
    </div>
    <div id="closeShip2">
      <div class="closeShipNMOther">8,9 nm</div>
      <div class="closeShipNameOther">RS 160 Horn Rescue</div>
    </div>
    <div id="closeShip3">
      <div class="closeShipNMOther">8,9 nm</div>
      <div ng-click="test()" class="closeShipNameOther">RS 160 Horn Rescue</div>
    </div>
    <div id="closeShipFooter">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#closeShipExpand" id="closeButtonClosestShip">Skjul <span id="crossClosestShip" class="closeCross"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that no events inside the collapsed DIV seems to respond. Not the `data-toggle` or the `ng-click`. If I put the DIV **outside** the "trigger DIV" all works fine. Is it something inside the "trigger DIV" that overrides or cancels all events fired inside it? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you create a plunk / fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1):

With bootstrap (and angular but my example with bootstrap) you don't need to put the div inside the collapse div.

The key is to set the `data-target` to the `id` of the collapse `div`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
Lorem ipsum dolor text....
</div>
```

Comment: I know, but I want to press a DIV and expand the very same DIV as I press. In your example it would be the button that would expand. Understand? :)

Comment: No, because the `collapse` div suppose to be hidden. So how can you click on it?

Comment: I have a DIV (trigger) inside a DIV (toBeCollapsed). When trigger is pressed it will collapse toBeCollapsed and in the same process expand the size of trigger.

Comment: toBeCollapsed = toBeExpanded :P

Comment: I'm missing you, can you create a snippet for this?

Comment: Hmm. I just created a Plunker and it seems to work fine there. :/ https://plnkr.co/edit/CE3sudxE6qScKXCreNQQ?p=preview

Comment: Well, I am not. Since it is not working in my application. :P

Comment: What exactly not working? Do you have any errors in the `console`?

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was the use z-index that was cousing another div to block the click event.